# How to get directory path from meson?

Tags: c, linux, path, meson-build

I have read following line from meson documentation

```
install_data('datafile.dat', install_dir : get_option('datadir') / 'progname')
```

This should install `datafile.dat` to `share/progname` when meson is run. I am using linux and it's not clear to me where `share/progname` actually is located in my computer. And in c programs how to I for example open that installed file? Running something like this doesn't work for me :

```
 FILE * fptr = fopen("share/progname/datafile.dat", "w");
   ....
```

Is share/progname something like a prefix which is a virtual path for a location? Or is it something else? How can I install my database file and access it from a c program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For installing meson will use prefix + `install_dir`, by default prefix is `/usr/local/`, so if you have:

```
install_data('datafile.dat', install_dir :'progname')
```

and call `ninja install`, `datafile.dat` will be installed in `'/usr/local/progname'`

in your case you have

```
install_data('datafile.dat', install_dir : get_option('datadir') / 'progname')
```

if you do not provide `-Dprefix` or `-Ddatadir`

`ninja install` will install it at `/usr/local/share/progname`

but you can tweak it with `-Dprefix` and `-Ddatadir` like this:

`meson -Dprefix='/path/to/prefix' -Ddatadir='other' ..`

and after calling `ninja install` it will be installed at `/path/to/prefix/other/progname`

Comment: I am using gnome-builder as my IDE. When I "export bundle" I can find my file installed in files/share/progname. Should I invoke ninja install command for it to be installed in /usr/local/share/progname? How can I manage that when distributing the project? Is there a way to call ninja install automatically somehow?

Comment: Well, you need to call ninja install for your datafile.dat to be installed. I am not sure what do you mean by distributing. When building from source, you use meson for configure, ninja for build and ninja install for installation. That is it.

Comment: @Vahan, if this solves your problem, please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to do so. Thanks for the again, I'll do that now.